# getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Passing_own_variable);

Tags: android, arrays, string, listview

I am printing some string data on listView where I am getting array from string-array from strings.xml. To make you more clearer I am giving an example:

**Strings.xml**

```
<string-array name="vehicle">
<item>car</item>
<item>bur</item>
<item>van</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="food">
<item>cake</item>
<item>donuts</item>
<item>Ice-cream</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="fruits">
<item>apple</item>
<item>banana</item>
<item>grapes</item>
</string-array>


 Now, Something In NavigationItem like:

 vehicle
 food
 fruits
```

then, when I select vehicle I start fargment like below and

```
  case R.id.vehicle:
                bundle.putString("key_variable","vehicle");
                msgListActivtiy loveweb=new msgListActivtiy();
                loveweb.setArguments(bundle);
                fragmentTransaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mainContainer,loveweb);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
                break;

   case R.id.foods:
                bundle.putString("key_variable","food");
                //othercodes
                break;

case R.id.fruits:
               bundle.putString("key_variable","fruits");
               //othercodes
               break;
```

Now, this opens a msgListActivity

Here's something Likethis

```
public class msgListActivtiy extends Fragment {
String localUrl;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Bundle bundle=this.getArguments();
    localUrl=bundle.getString("key_variable","defaultvalue");
    View rootView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.lv,container,false);
    ListView listView= (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview);
  //Now, below instead of giving car I need to set the localvariable that I 
//have declared above.
  //Something I want to pass like
//String[] res="getActivity().getResources().getStringArray(R.array."+localvariable+");"; I tried this and give me error like found string instead of String[]
//how can we achieve that? If that can't be done then how do we handle these kinds of situations??
    String[] res=getActivity().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.need_variable_from_bundle_above);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,res);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    return rootView;
```

Comment: @Exigente05 I have said in comments in code. Title itself is question. How can we pass the own_variable in R.array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get id of that array,

Assume we are working with "vehicle" array

```
int resId = getResources().getIdentifier("vehicle", "array", getActivity().getPackageName());
```

Then use this id

```
String[] res = getResources().getStringArray(resId);
```

Comment: Yes, working!! I get what I wanted!! Thank you so much Exigente05, You're perfect!!